# Bluetooth Health Device Profile (HDP) Sink Implementation in BlueZ 4.99?

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth, profile, bluez

I am new to Bluetooth programming, and I am trying to create a Linux application which interacts with a Heart Rate Monitor (HRM) over Bluetooth. This would ideally be accomplished through either BlueZ tools (sdptool, hcitool, hciconfig, etc.) or the C Programming Language.

I assume the program would resemble the following:

1. Scan nearby devices.
2. Browse SDP of each device, searching for an HDP HRM Source.
3. Perform some sort of connection command.
4. Read from stream/file passed by connection command.

Of course, being new, my assumptions about program flow could be incorrect themselves.

However, I am unable to find any capabilities regarding the Health Device Profile in the BlueZ tools. In attempting to make a C application, I can find preprocessor macros for numbers relating to an HDP implementation in the BlueZ header files, but no functionality beyond that.

Some useful links I've found:

- [HDP V10 Specifications](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluetooth.org%2FDocMan%2Fhandlers%2FDownloadDoc.ashx%3Fdoc_id%3D119999&ei=MzV8UMbaOeGe2QWuwYHwBg&usg=AFQjCNFQfqxV7ZP6WTNcZLWVFHNht6GNHw&sig2=dIc1lJL3VHL-9XUkE4tG6Q&cad=rja) (PDF)
- [BlueZ HDP Python Example](http://epx.com.br/artigos/bluetooth_hdpbluez.php)

System Information:

- Linux Kernel: 2.6.37
- BlueZ Version: 4.99
- D-Bus Version: 1.0

To be more specific about my questions, is it possible to create an HDP sink using BlueZ tools? If not, is it possible to do so in C. If not, what is the best way? And where can I go to find documentation for HDP connections and possible examples. Search engines have proved unhelpful so far, so I am hoping SO can provide some direction.

Thanks!

Comment: So what's wrong with the python example you linked to?

Answer (score 0):

Try Antidote, it compiles for Linux and has a built-in sink example
(healthd).

http://oss.signove.com/index.php/Antidote:_IEEE_11073-20601_stack